method_frame always return None when using channel.basic_get
I am trying to consume several messages from RabbitMQ queue without success.
I want to use basic_consume function and if there are more messages then pull them (instead of being called again to the callback function).
import pika
import time


class RabbitMQPublisher:
    def __init__(self, queue_name):
        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel    = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name)

    def publish_messages(self, num_messages):
        for i in range(num_messages):
            message = f'Message {i+1}'
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self.queue_name, body=message)
            print(f'Sent: {message}')

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.close()

class RabbitMQConsumer:
    def __init__(self, queue_name):
        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel    = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name)

    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        print(f'Received: {body.decode()}')
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        self.pull_remaining_messages()

    def pull_remaining_messages(self):
        method_frame, header_frame, body = self.channel.basic_get(queue=self.queue_name, auto_ack=False)
        print(f"method_frame = {method_frame}")
        while method_frame:
            print(f'---> [pull_remaining_messages] Received: {body.decode()}')
            self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
            method_frame, header_frame, body = self.channel.basic_get(queue=self.queue_name, auto_ack=False)

    def start_consuming(self):
        self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue_name, on_message_callback=self.callback, auto_ack=False)
        print('Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
        self.channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    publisher = RabbitMQPublisher('test_queue')
    publisher.publish_messages(100)
    publisher.close_connection()

    time.sleep(2)

    consumer = RabbitMQConsumer('test_queue')
    consumer.start_consuming()

Using the code above - I always get method_frame = None.
What am I missing ?
